# BsonSerializationException - Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, string>> type

Tags: c#, mongodb, dictionary, serialization, mongodb-query

I am trying to save a document in MongoDb which has a member, FinishedGoodsMap, that looks something like the following.

```
[BsonDictionaryOptions(DictionaryRepresentation.ArrayOfArrays)]
public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, string>> FinishedGoodsMap { get; set; }
```

When trying to update the document in my mongo data store, I am faced with the following exception:

> BsonSerializationException: When using DictionaryRepresentation.Document key values must serialize as strings.

As you can see, my key value for the member dictionary is in fact a string, and the nested dictionary cannot change its type. Strangely enough though, I have other dictonaries on this document that do not have string type keys..

I have tried serializing the member in every way that [the docs](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.2/reference/bson/mapping/#dictionary-serialization-options) allow - Document, ArrayOfDocuments, ArrayOfArrays.

Can anyone help me solve this error? I would prefer not to change data types.

**edit**: I got around this by changing the structure of the dictionary, with one composite key that maps to a string - but I am still wondering if there is a way to solve this.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the link you included. It was exactly what I needed. :)